# MSI 760GM-P23 FX motherboard, AMD FX 4300 cpu & 1333 ddr3 ram won't POST

Tags: boot, post

I've built a new computer with:

- MSI 760GM-P23 FX motherboard,
- AMD FX 4300 CPU
- 2x8Gb of 1333 DDR3 RAM

On power up, everything runs, motherboard splash screen comes up, system will not POST, cannot enter into CMOS. Display says "Please select the boot device". CD/DVD: Optiarc DVD RW AD-7290H is listed.

If I select this it says "No bootable device, Press any key to go back". All parts are new. Beep is heard on start up.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a boot-able disk in the optical drive, and seeing if the system will boot off the disk?

Comment: @Joe, POST happens before it attempts to boot, are you sure about this sequence?  Is it a single beep?

Answer (score 1):

> On power up, everything runs, motherboard splash screen comes up, system will not POST,

If your system has got to a point of spash screen and that it askes you to select a boot device, it has passed POST (Power on self test). This is good news so far.

> cannot enter into CMOS.

I think you are looking to get into BIOS. This is done on MSI boards (Just like my 790FX -GD70) by tapping the Delete key BEFORE the spash screen clears. I tap several times right after I push the power button until I see that drives and USB items are listing on the screen. Then the BIOS screen should appear.

You do not list a hard drive in your configuration, but if one is installed, be sure the SATA cable is plugged in securely. BIOS should see the drive if it is connected and functioning.

You do not mention an OS, so if HDD is new and no OS is installed, put in your OS DVD into CD/DVD drive and select CD/DVD: Optiarc DVD RW AD-7290H as your boot device. The OS should load.